# Subiquity installer via ipxe not properly loading autoinstall file?

Tags: pxe, subiquity

I'm trying to move our company to use the new Subiquity installer.
We currently run an ipxe setup that calls the old Debian installer, which I have converted to kick off subiquity instead. The issue is that no matter what I try, it keeps skipping the auto configured stuff, and just plainly jumps to interactive right away.

Ipxe section that calls subiquity:

```
:ubuntu-subiquity
set ubuntu-installer-base ubuntu-21.04-live-server-amd64
kernel ${url}/ubuntu/${release}/init/vmlinuz
initrd ${url}/ubuntu/${release}/init/initrd
imgargs vmlinuz initrd=initrd \
 ip=dhcp \
 url=${url}/ubuntu/${release}/${ubuntu-installer-base}.iso \
 autoinstall \
 ds=nocloud-net;s=${url}/ubuntu/${release}/autoinstall.yaml \
 interface=auto \
 netcfg/link_wait_timeout=10 \
 netcfg/dhcp_timeout=60
boot || goto failed
```

There's a autoinstall.yaml file as well as the plain 21.04 ISO.

This is the content of the autoinstall.yaml:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: lnxclnt8888
    username: testuser
    password: $6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  keyboard:
    layout: us
    variant: ''
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    install-server: true
  packages:
    - avahi-daemon
    - avahi-autoipd
    - build-essential
    - ubuntu-desktop
  late-commands:
    - rm /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
    - echo "network: \n  version: 2 \n renderer: NetworkManager" >> /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
    - netplan apply
  user-data:
    disable_root: true
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot wrap my head around why it's not kicking off the autoinstaller...

This is the debug server log (sorry for the image, could not copy this):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRAd4.jpg)

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 is out of support and as such off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
ds=nocloud-net;s=${url}/ubuntu/${release}/
```

with this folder containing

```
user-data
meta-data
```

Source: [nocloud](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html)